# Recording Returns - Voice Msg Too Short

Tags: ivr

I have an Electronic Workforce (EWF) application that records the caller speaking.  The system needs to record for 120 seconds then play a message and hangup.  I set a maximum length of 120 seconds and a minimum length of 1 second.  I didn't want any input to disrupt the recording, so I checked "Discard Earlier User Input", "Tone Input Stops Recording" (with keys that stop recording = ""), and "Discard the Key".

I also added "VCE.RECORD.beeptime = 0" to the cta.cfg file to the remove the beep before the recording.  To the cta file I also added "VCE.RECORD.gain = 2" to increase the volume of the recordings and "VCE.RECORD.silencetime = 120000" to allow up to 120 seconds of silence if the user doesn't say anything to be recorded.

These settings all worked fine in my testing in that the only way I was able to get a file shorter than 120 seconds was to hangup early.  Now that we have gone live though, customers seem to have found a way to get a file consistently five seconds long.  We have about 120 recordings a day and about 10 a day are exactly five seconds long.  The exception returned is "Voice Msg Too Short".

My question is how is this happening and what can I do (if anything) to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User -BMM- on the Edify/Intervoice/Convergys customer forum gave me a good answer to this question.  There are two settings that can cause a recording step to timeout with the Voice Msg Too Short error as follows...

```
VCE.RECORD.novoicetime = 0
VCE.RECORD.silencetime = 0
```

The value is in seconds, but zero disables the timeouts entirely so that silence at the start of a sound and silence at the end do not cause the exception to be thrown.